# Flushing S3 DiskCache for single image

Tags: imageresizer

I am testing DiskCache with S3Reader2 for an imagecollection and it caches very nice and seemless.
However I have a hard time finding any info on clearing the diskcache for an image - which I need after image-update.

Is that possible via querystring? Or via C# Code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

S3Reader2 [supports invalidation in V4+](http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/s3reader2) with a sliding expiration window.

You can also take the easy approach and append "&cachebreaker=x" when your underlying file changes. This has the benefit of working immediately and across CDNs.

Comment: ok thanks - I ended up using the cachebuster approach for images which must be updated immidiately and the checkForModifiedFiles="true" in general